# Hide Resume button when video has ended

Tags: roku, brightscript

Roku application with VOD feature.

I have used 3 buttons namely Resume, Play from beginning, Play in the Menu. When i come out of the video at halfway point through the resume button is available in the menu and when i click on it, the video plays from where it was stopped/Paused.

The issue is after the video ends the resume button still persists and i want to get rid of the Resume button only when the video is ended not half way through.

I have used msg.isfullResult() to detect the end of video but still that Resume button persists.

Also i want to know how to create a unique ID in registry so that even if users go out of the application and return back i still want to have resume feature. Help me out.

Kindly add reference or code to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For persistent resume functionality I would not suggest you to store the position in registry for videos. You should store data somewhere in a database and access it with API.

While loading first and in msg.isFullResult, You can use clearButtons(void) function to remove all the buttons and add back the buttons with the function AddButton(Integer id, String title), You should check  AllowUpdates(Boolean) too if you adding and removing buttons dynamically so as to avoid flashing. You would need to show the button 'Resume' and "Play from beginning" only if you have a position saved for the specific video, else you can just show play button. While removing and adding back buttons, keep the id of the buttons same as they were before. Like if you had id 1 for play, 2 for resume and 3 for resume playing then when you clear and add back the button the id for play should be 1 and for resume 2 ...

Hope this gives you idea about handing the resume functionality and buttons.